# Choosing data based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set that tracks in product use. Some of the features used in the timeframe captured is extremely unrealistic. I want to select data that meets a specific filter.

```
status                                            1
crm_customer_guid          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
product_name                                   XXXX
event_source                                  PROMO
offer_type                                    TRIAL
date_cohort                                  9/9/18
market_area                                      US
webservices_users                                 1
mobile_users                                      1
fiscal_yr_and_per_desc                      2018-12
fiscal_yr_and_qtr_desc                      2018-Q4
fiscal_yr_and_wk_desc                       2018-48
total_sessions                                 1107
Feature1                                       539
Feature2                                       864
Feature3                                       198
Feature4                                       0
Feature5                                       277
Feature6                                       1458
Feature7                                       899
Feature8                                       321
Feature9                                       716
Feature10                                      282
Feature11                                      1396
```

I want to filter all feature numbers < 20 and insert those rows into a new data frame.

I tried using

```
df_engaged = df[(((df['total_sessions'] > 2) & (df['total_sessions'] < 10)) & ((df['feature3'] < 11) & (df['feature4'] < 11)))]
```

To add all of the features, it seem's this approach is inefficient.

Any advice is great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that actually how your data is arranged, or is that the transpose? Can you provide your expected output, because it's unclear what this should look like in the end,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can slice the Features part of dataframe and filter

```
#Change the Feature# here
for i in range(5,11):
    df[df['Feature'+str(i)] < 20] = None

    new_df = df.dropna()
```